# Something going wrong in mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am newbie and learning php yet. I am trying to run some mysqli_query but its giving me some errors. My code is like below.

```html
<?php
ob_start();
include("db.php"); 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM contest");
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['automated'] ==1){
            echo 'Atomatic is enabled';
            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `contest` SET automated =0"
     $new =  mysqli_query($conn,$result1);
      echo 'Atomatic is Disabled';
        }
        else{
            echo 'Atomatic is Disabled';
        }
    }
```

can somebody check and please suggest me whats wrong in this query ? its giving me error like **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$new'** and similar if I change it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close patenthesis.`()`..

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `contest` SET automated =0");//error was here
```